# Is it possible to open a port for listening without netcat?

Tags: linux, networking, bash, python, perl

I have a need for a Linux system to listen on a TCP port and dump what it receives to a file and/or stdout. The system does not have netcat installed. I have root permissions, but am not allowed to add new applications to the system for compliance reasons. Is it possible to do this with a simple bash, perl, or python script? The simpler, the better.

Comment: do you have tcpdump available?  tcpdump -vv -x -X -s 1500 -i eth1 'port 25' -w /somewhere/dump.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open a random port using Python:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 0))
```

To find out which port you have opened:

```
s.getsockname()[1]
```

To close the port:

```
s.close()
```

For more information, read [the documentation for the socket module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html), [the socket how-to](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html), or [a socket tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm).